# Blender's cube projection unwrapping doesn't work anymore in Unity

Tags: uv, game-engine, unity

I have Unwrapped my level in Blender using the cube projection Option. the results were exactly what I wanted[image][image][image]

The level looked also looked fine in Unity for a while. However I'm not sure what happened but right now unity is not unwrapping them properly[image][image]

Besides unwrapping every single texture manually I don't know what to do and I would definitely need some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the texture still correct in blender? Did the mesh change? How are you bring it into unity?

Comment: Did Unity add on extra materials to your mesh? Open up the mesh renderer and check. I think if you change it to 0 and assign your grid texture, that should do it. Another thing you could try is delete the model/texture from Unity and re-import them.

Comment: I have solved the problem by finding this link:  https://answers.unity.com/questions/826967/textures-on-models-messed-up.html    Apparently my texture has been set to "clamp" instead of "repeat". I'm not sure why though. I wanna say thanks again for commenting